# download size of ARC Welder extension

Tags: linux, google-chrome-arc

I am using Google Chrome version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) in ubuntu 14.04.1.
I recently downloaded ARC Welder extension from chrome web store(see the image below).

In the app store it was mentioned  that the size of the app is 11mb.. but when i try to download it downloaded a single crx file around 120mb before the download failed...

can anybody tell me what is the actual download size of the ARC Welder extension (.crx file size.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It downloaded two crx files. One was about 120MB, and the other around 15MB.

I believe the large file was the ARC:

> Note: If you do not have any ARC Apps, installing ARC Welder will automatically download and install ARC, a large one time download.

Then the last file was the actual ARC Welder app.

See here:
[ARC Welder in Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn)

Answer (score 0):

First one is arc welder app and another one is a .crx file that arc welder needs to run apps. Their total size would be approximately 140 MB.

Comment: For me one .crx file was 183 Mb, the other was 12Mb.